# Problems forcing a page break in HTML on printing

Tags: html, css

I am trying to force a page break on to the printed version of my page. I am doing this by styling sections that I want to break into a new page. The problem I am having is that when I print an empty page is inserted between the elements. So the page break is working but adding an extra blank page between.

For example the below code should print two pages but it actually prints 4 in total (the two I want and two blank pages).

here is the full html code of the page , including css below;

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <meta name="theme-color" content="#000000" />
    <meta
      name="description"
      content="Web site created using create-react-app"
    />
 
    <title>DEMO</title>
    <style type="text/css">
      /* JUST IMPORTS , RESTS & MINIMAL DEFAULTS */
      /* CSS reset */
      * {
        padding: 0;
        margin: 0;
      }

      .container-flex-column {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
      }
      .page-width-mobi {
        min-width: 1072px;
        max-width: 1072px;
      }
      .new-page {
        page-break-before: always;
        box-sizing: border-box;
        border-bottom: solid lightgray 20px;
      }
      .page-size-mobi {
        min-height: 1505px;
        max-height: 1505px;
        min-width: 1072px;
        max-width: 1072px;
      }
    </style>
  </head>

  <body>
    <main class="container-flex-column page-width-mobi">
      <section class="new-page  page-size-mobi">
        <h1>Page 1</h1>
      </section>
      <section class="new-page   page-size-mobi">
        <h1>Page 2</h1>
      </section>
    </main>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem I was having was that I was printing the document with an old version of safari. Safari did not consistently work with the break-before command. I was able to produce the desired outcome printing in an up to date version of chrome

The break commands and the @page css commands are new functionality and not widely supported